# SIGABRT ERROR Swift (Line let currentPlayers)

Tags: swift, macos

```
@IBAction func nameSet(_ sender: Any) {
        if textField.text != "" {
            //let userInput = textName.text

            performSegue(withIdentifier: "currentPlayers", sender: self)
        }



    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

  let currentPlayers = segue.destination *--< Sigabrt Error Thread1*
as!currentPlayersViewController;
        currentPlayers.myString = textField.text!






    }
```

Help! thank you. I'm getting an error where I click on the button and It performs this error. I want to my player to enter text into the textfield but show the text on another view controller. When I do this and get it set up it performs the error on the "let currentPlayers = segue.destination"

Comment: Sure **segue.destination** is of **currentPlayersViewController** type ??

Comment: Do you have more than one segue, because you should be checking `if segue.identifier == "currentPlayers"` in `prepare(for:sender:)`.

Comment: What is the full error message?